# How can I get Django to create a unique URL view and page for each URLField entered

Tags: python, django, view, url-routing

I'm trying to create a small app in a django project where when a URL is inputted into the URLField form, then a separate page is created for each URL creating a sort of directory page for each link people submit. For example, if I enter the URL http://www.facebook.com/username1 or http://www.facebook.com/username2 I'd like django to create a new page at www.mysite.com/username1 and www.mysite.com/username2 respectively. What's the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance very much! Here is my basic code for the Form field:

```
class newlinkform(forms.ModelForm):
    link_comment = forms.CharField(max_length=256) #comment to go along with URL entered
    url = forms.URLField(max_length = 512) #actual submitted link I'd like to get a view mapped to


    class Meta:
        model = newlink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had something like this in your `urls.py`:

```
...
url(r'URL/^(?P<url_param>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$', 'views.view_for_all_pages', name='view_for_all_pages')
...
```

Then your views.py could look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render as render_original
def view_for_all_pages ( request, url_param ):
    render (request, "template.html", { "url_param" : url_param })
```

And your template:

```
<h1>URL entered: {{url_param}}</h1>
```

Then you could request: `http://yourserver.com:8000/URL/foo` to see `<h1>URL entered: foo</h1>`

Comment: Thanks for the great start. I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work in practice, but I get the jist of what is going on. When I implement all of this though I get an attribute error "'str' object has no attribute 'META'" 
Is this because the url_param expects a different input than whatever I am supplying it?
Also, does this mean that the page created using that view will be at something like mysite.com/url/http:/ /facebook.com/username1? Or does the http:// portion get sripped?

Comment: Oups. My mistake - was typing the code without checking. The 'META' error came from the render () call line - I updated it to have the first argument a request, not the template name.

Comment: Thanks a plenty! I got it working with your help. Much appreciated!